# AWS secret manger seceret string parsing to yaml error

Tags: go, aws-secrets-manager

I am running the aws seceret manager where all the details are kept, I am able retrive data using go lang, but when I am trying to set data in yaml format, I get parse error. below is code.

> PANIC cmd/main.go:71  unable to load configWhile parsing config: yaml: line 11: could not find expected ':' last line.

yaml format

```
psql:
  db: dev
  auth: postgres://localhost:5432"
qldb:
  region: ""
  ledger: ""
cognito:
  token_endpoint: ""
  issuer: ""
  login_url: ""
```

main.go

```
func main (){

 c, err := Secretmanager.Getconfig() // string type contains all secerect mananger connection deatils
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }


}

viper.SetConfigType("yaml")
    err = viper.ReadConfig(strings.NewReader(c)) // error here
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("unable to load config", err)
    }
```